# JWT- Decode require not defined, jwt decode not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, jwt, decode

Im having problem using JWT decode cant seem to make this work

```
var token = 'eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token';

var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(decoded);
```

with this require

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
enter code here
```

i have already npm install jwt-decode and also try
jwt-simple

i just want to decode the payload in the easiest way possible

please help me this is my code

```
<script>

var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
var token = 'eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ';

var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(decoded);

function myFunction() {
  alert(decoded);
}
</script>
```

```
<script src='/js/jwt-decode.js'></script>
<script>

        var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
        var token = 'eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ';

        var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
        console.log(decoded);

        function myFunction() {
          alert(decoded);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to download library https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode
Then simply use

```
<script src="js/jwt-decode.min.js"></script>

var token = 'eyJ0eXAiO.../// your jwt token';
var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
console.log(decoded);
```

Comment: hi @riajul when i pass the decoded to alert it shows [object object] but the console.log works fine. what is the problem with the alert js, thanks

Comment: Solution is working perfectly. console.log can working perfectly with object but alert cannot working perfectly with long object. though you can show  any element at alert like as alert(object.element) thanks waiting for your upvote :P

Comment: SUGGESTION: never use alert to show any object, just use console.log for object, array or any long data. alert use for one or two line string type data

Comment: got your point. but i need the data to show in any form like text input, label, div id's etc. is there another way? i tried to put it inside a div using getelementid and append and the output is object object too.

Comment: still object object appears when appending the decode to a div, or id :(

Comment: @MichaelBenGabriel its not problem of token decode. Its problem of showing javascript object data in html element. Please study about "how to show javascript object data into html element" or you can post another question with description of your problem. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

`require` is not defined in the browser. Instead, you would need to include the library file via a script tag. You can obtain the library file [here](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/v2.2.0/build/jwt-decode.js).

You can copy and paste the code there into a `jwt-decode.js` file.
Example:

```html
<script src='./jwt-decode.js'></script>
<script>
   const decoded = jwt_decode(jwtToken);
   console.log(decoded);
</script>
```

Comment: hi, jro already changed my code but the error is this
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
Reference error: require is not defined

Comment: If you are running in the browser you would need to use script tags to include the library. If you are running in the browser please specify in your question

Comment: Updated answer with browser env

Comment: required is still not defined, im losing hope with myself

Comment: @MichaelBenGabriel You should remove all the requires from browser code